# Precision loss from real arithmetic operations

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, real-numbers, numerical-linear-algebra

I feel like this is a dumb question, but I'm looking for a reference for theoretical precision loss of real number operations such as addition, multiplication, division, and scalar multiplication.
Google seems to mostly return stuff related to computer representations which is not quite what I want.

As an example: define $a'$ to be a $q$-approximation of a if $|a'-a| < 2^{-q}$.
Suppose that $a'$ and $b'$ are $q$-approximations of $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ respectively.
Then $a' +b'$ is a $q-1$ approximation of $a+b$ since
$$|(a+b) -(a'+b')| \leq |a-a'| + |b-b'| < 2\cdot 2^{-q} = 2^{-(q-1)}.$$

I realize these would be easy enough to prove, but a nice reference would give me some peace of mind, and a good learning reference as I consider more complicated algorithms. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually in real arithmetic operations you work with floating point. Then the mostly relevant error is the relative one, $|a'-a|<2^{-q}|a|$ etc. Then the addition has an error multiplier of $\frac{|a|+|b|}{|a+b|}$ which highlights the possibility of catastrophic cancellation if $a$ and $b$ are of same magnitude but opposite sign.

Comment: Oh I see, do you mean I should be using an error factor instead of adding and subtracting precision order? Also do you perhaps know of any papers/ texts that I can check to get a better idea?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. The absolute error is more relevant for fixed-point number types, the relative error for floating-point. There is a theory called "backward error analysis" that might be what you are looking for. Essentially, it estimates by how much one would have to change the inputs of the numerical evaluation to get the numerical value as value of the exact function. One result is that orthogonal/unitary operations in linear algebra like QR decomposition or FFT are surprisingly well-behaved.